# How to call UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession()

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an app that has a button to lock, and another button to unlock.

Lock - This button will lock device. Only this app's screen will show nothing else will be accessible even after restart same screen will show up. Home button, gestures will get disabled similar to single app mode.

Unlock - This will unlock device and switch to normal behavior of device.

Here's what I tried:

```
@IBAction func lock(sender: UIButton)
{
    UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(true) {
        success in
        println("\(success)") // success is false
    }
}


@IBAction func unlock(sender: UIButton)
{
    UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(false) {
        success in
        println("\(success)") // success is false
    }
}
```

When I lock it and then press the home button, it goes home. Am I doing anything wrong? What can I do to fix it?

P.S. I'm new to `swift` coming from `Objective-c`

Comment: You need to enable Single App Mode in MDM (Mobile Device Management). Namely, you need to configure a profile and add your app's bundle identifier to 'autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs'

Comment: Thanks again for helping! How can I enable that?

Comment: Apple Configurator (From App Store, by Apple) should help.

Comment: Once I do that, will it work with any iphone that downloads my app from the app store?

Comment: no, this api is restricted to MDM provisioned devices to prevent abuse. Unrestricted access to this API could lead to DoS attacks (although  Apple would never approve)

Comment: Is there a way to let the user give permission?

Comment: As Nightawk441 mentioned you need permission from Apple. Get it from here http://www.apple.com/education/it/mdm/