# Enable/disable guided access programmatically objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to enable/disable Guided Access from my app.

Here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"requesting guided access");
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(YES, ^(BOOL didSucceed) {
    if (didSucceed) {
        NSLog(@"entered guided access");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"failed to enter guided access");
    }
});
```

always getting **didSucceed=NO**

Don't know what is the issue

Is there any thing else to do ?

Do i need MDM profile or any thing else for this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you do, at least according to the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059905/how-to-call-uiaccessibilityrequestguidedaccesssession).

Comment: This the comment there

"You need to enable Single App Mode in MDM (Mobile Device Management). Namely, you need to configure a profile and add your app's bundle identifier to 'autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs'"

But i don't now anything about MDM and how to add bundle identifier..
can you guid me step by step..

Comment: I've never done it myself.

Answer (score 0):

thats the way for enabling the Single App mode. However, to do so the device has to be supervised, and have an MDM profile installed that has the app's bundle ID in the list of applications that can request guided access mode the key is `autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSAccessibility_Protocol_Reference/